# Why JS function not working when I take it out of JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Similar questions have been asked before BUT all/most of them suggested that I used this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put your Javascript here
});
```

Even with using that It still does not work:

Code is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ooexfj26/

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Johnn</td>
              <td>Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sam</td>
              <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">EDIT</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p><input type="text" class="input-sm" id="txtfname"/></p>
            <p><input type="text" class="input-sm" id="txtlname"/></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
    <script src="modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('table tbody tr  td').on('click', function () {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    $("#txtfname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);
    $("#txtlname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
  });
});
```

I have even tried adding these at the end still no difference:

```
  <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result:
All components of html show and no JS functionality seems to be present

Comment: You need to add jquery before yours.  Either of those jquery links will be fine, but of course not both, that would be silly. :)

Comment: Where is your bootstrap js reference?

Comment: Have you have included your bootstrap script? It's not in the code you showed.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be loading 2 versions of jQuery.

Comment: I'm not adding both versions of JQuery at the same time. I'm thinking it is something to do with the bootstrap, as I have not referenced that and its not in the JSFiddle HTML

Comment: Sidenote/off topic: you can simplyfy this selector to `$("tbody td")` as the other two selectors are pointless; or even to plain `$("td")` as you have 'th's in the table header. Because, where else yould you find a table cell in HTML than inside a table row? And where else would that be, than inside a table? Only the `tbody` adds some value to the selector, as it would exclude the table cells inside a `thead` or `tfoot`, if there were any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Because you need bootstrap scripts, bootstrp css and jquery script.

I tested it [here](https://refork.com/x3a0), it works.

Comment: Correct but the JQuery version needs to be:                                                                      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>                                                               Please update so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: yes, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You **need** `jQuery` for your code to work. Try using this `CDN` since it's more recent than the versions you attempted to use.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And be sure that you insert this **before** your JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. I have done exactly as you have said.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? What's the problem??

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is extremely general

Comment: The behaviour is exactly the same as before. No visible errors, The html loads the table and the modal.all on one page. there seems to be no JS functionality

Comment: Have you also included the `BootstrapJS`?

Comment: View my updated answer,

Comment: Chriwi answer fixes my problem, yours is close but stylesheets should be referenced in a different way with 'link rel'. Otherwise I would give you +1 (if I had the reputation to do so ofcourse)